# Printing to PDF in Texmaker gives source code instead of rendered output

Tags: compiling, texmaker, tex-general

When I print to pdf, I do not get the actual pdf that is shown in TexMaker. Instead I get the "code" I used. Why is this? How do I fix it?

I wrote my homework for my Real Analysis class in LaTeX and had no problem using Quick Build to view the pdf as I worked.  When I finished and attempted to print it, it only gives me the code, not the actual finished product.  I have attached a couple of photos so you can see what I mean.  I am still very new to using LaTeX, but I have used it for homework assignments last semester and had no trouble printing it to a pdf.  To my knowledge I did not change any settings, but I suddenly cannot create a printable pdf of my work.

This is the view in Texmaker, no issues:
[image: Screenshot of Partial view from Texmaker]

This is a screenshot of the pdf that is created:
[image: Screenshot of the pdf generated when I print to pdf]

I have also tried skipping the step of creating a pdf and printing straight to the printer and that also just prints the code and not the finished product.

Any assistance with fixing this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Open the pdf file and print it from there. :)

Comment: When I open the pdf file it looks like the second image I attached.  Just the source code.  This is the issue.

Comment: How do you compile your document? You mention that you "print to pdf", which sounds a bit like if that is a different option in Texmaker beside the normal document compilation process.

Comment: When I compile it I usually use "Quick Build" which is set to View PDF.  I use this while I am working and the PDF is correctly displayed alongside the code.  When I finished I wanted to print it out, so I just went to File -> Print and it prints the source code to the printer.  I tried to make it print as a PDF under File -> Print and then selecting my laptops method for saving as a PDF and that gives the source code as well.

Comment: So it seems TeXmaker prints the source code instead of the final document. I don't know if TeXmaker provides a command for directly printing the PDF file, but you can always open it in an external PDF viewer and print it from there.